# sourcing env output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have some shell code I need to be debug, so I had the code dump its environment into a file

```
env > env.txt
```

and with my testing script I want to source it, test.sh:

```
. ./env.txt
echo $EXAMPLE
echo $EXAMPLE2
```

the contents of env.txt are:

```
EXAMPLE=sh /hello/command.sh
EXAMPLE2=/just/some/path
```

but, env does not put quotes around its values, which tends to cause a issue for $EXAMPLE, I get this error

test.sh: /hello/command.sh: not found

so clearly it is trying to run it instead of setting the variables.

what do you find is the quickest workaround for this problem?

Comment: Hm, `set > env.txt` sets all & quotes all, but that is no help with your current env.txt of course...

Comment: Note that `env > env.txt` will only record *environment* variables, but `. ./env.txt` will set Bash variables *without* exporting them. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: In some shells, `set > env.txt` will redirect standard output from that point on to `env.txt`. For portability, it's safer to do `(set) > env.txt`.

Comment: I did not know set could do that. very useful thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
while read line; do
    declare "$line"
    # declare -x "$line"
    # export "$line"
done < env.txt
```

If you want to export the values to the environment, use the `-x` option to `declare` or use the `export` command instead.

Answer (score 12):

Add the double quotes before redirecting the output to a file:

```
env | sed 's/=\(.*\)/="\1"/' > env.txt
```

Comment: +1 because the OP asked for "the quickest workaround", but this isn't a very robust solution. For example, it will break if any variable-values contain newlines or backslashes or dollar-signs.

Answer (score 1):

```
while read line; do
 var="${line%=*}"
 value="${line##*=}"
 eval "$var=\"$value\""
done <env.txt
```

Comment: No need for `eval`. Just use `declare "$line"`, or `export "$line"` if you want to export the parameter as well.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need the `_` variable, `export` shows all variables, and quote the ones that need it.

**Note:** export is a shell built-in and output differs depending on the shell/

```
$>printenv | grep "^LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=
$>env | grep "^LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=
# ksh & zsh
$>export -p | grep "^LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=''
# bash ; remove declare -x
$>export -p | cut -d" " -f3- | grep "^LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=''
# dash ; remove export
$>export -p | cut -d" " -f2- | grep "^LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=''
```

See manpages of your shell.