# print environment variable to reuse

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to save all environment variables and after that
reuse them.

I try to use env/source without success.
For example:

```
export V1="a b"
env | grep V1 > env.save
source env.save
bash: b: command not found
```

So env/printenv print environment variables in such form
that standard utility to read envronemnt variable can not handle it.

So is any standard POSIX utilites U1 and U2 such as
U1 can write env variables in the form that U2 can read them?

P.S.

Of course on any script language I can write such stuff in 30 minutes,
but I hope that tools for such trivial task already exists.

Comment: This is because `env | grep V1` returns `V1=a b` and not `V1="a b"`. Hence, it does `V1=a` and then tries to execute `b` as a command.

Comment: Yes, I know why this happening. Why this happend actually not important for me, the problem in save/restore functionality. source/env/printenv utilities are examples of utilities to "save" and "restore", my problem that theese standard utilties are designed for full cycle "save/restore", they can work together.

Comment: Now I see this question that might help: [sourcing env output](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15235729/1983854)

Answer (score 3):

This may help

```
export > env.save
```

or

```
typeset -gx > env.save
```

then

```
source env.save
```